# Separator line issues - uitableview cells with different heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with different cell heights. I have added a custom separator line also using the following code

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, cellReport.frame.size.height-1, table.frame.size.width-1, 1)];
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[cellReport.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

When i scroll my table extra separators appear between the rows and i dont understand why? Am i missing something? help me out.
In short UITableView displays separator at wrong position for some cells. Have attached an example image for reference.

**P.S: I AM NOT USING AUTOLAYOUT**

[image]

Comment: try this frame : CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x,cell.frame.size.height-1,cell.frame.size.width,1)

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati Actually i have used that only in my code. It didnot work. I have edited my answer. Please take a look

Comment: are you using custom cell? then replace **cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView** with ** cellReport.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView** may be there is problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow these steps

And do not need to every time your separator view. And set your frame every time.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *myIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell  *Cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];

    UIView* separatorLineView;

    if (Cell == nil)
    {

        Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];

        separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        separatorLineView.tag = 100;
        [Cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
    }

    separatorLineView = (UIView *)[Cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];

    separatorLineView.frame = CGRectMake(0, Cell.frame.size.height-1, Cell.frame.size.width, 1);

}
```